# Files copied to folder in var/www disappears on restart

Tags: lamp, permissions

I have a LAMP server setup. I have the source folder in my desktop which I can edit without 'sudo'ing. Then, I sync the files to var/www using sudo rsync. I gave the folders in var/www necessary permissions (770 for the mentioned folder,  since www-data is added to root group, and apache has to write to this directory, that is upload directory). It works well. But, when I restart the computer,  files in the upload folder in var/www disappears. I cannot understand what is happening.

```
  drwxrwxr-x 2 root www-data 4096 Dec 15 08:26 uploaded_files
```

my folder permissions look like this.

**EDIT:** The files disappear some time after the upload.

I'm just confused like hell.

Any help will be appreciated. I'm a newbie in linux file, folder permission btw.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had my source files in my Desktop, and I was syncing with var/www manually so that I don't have to sudo files individually. I was achieving this by syncing the entire desktop folder whenever I felt syncing is necessary. I used the '--delete' bit in my rsync command, so that any extra files in the destination which might have been deleted in my Desktop source, will be removed.

Here is the catch: I have a `/upload/dir` in my desktop, but nothing really gets uploaded, since it is done in document root, which is `/var/www/`. So, whenever I sync files, my Desktop `/upload/dir` (which is empty and will always be) replaces the `/upload/dir` in the document root. Hence the content disappeared.

Moral (for me & new linux users): Never blindly copy commands in terminal, without getting a basic understanding.

Answer (score 0):

They're either not saved, or removed. Check if /var/www isn't on a tmpfs (that's like a RAM disk, files are not saved to disk but kept in memory and so will disappear on reboot):

```
df -hT /var/www
```

and see what's under "Type". For example, I keep my logs on a tmpfs:

```
$ df -hT /var/log 
Filesystem     Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs          tmpfs  3.9G  672K  3.9G   1% /var/log
```

Comment: actually, it disappears a few minutes after uploading. It happens even after giving 777 permissions

Comment: /dev/sda6      ext4   46G  8.8G   35G  21% / /var/www it lists as ext4

Comment: my other files in var/www are intact